# Cantor set nowhere dense but still perfect?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, cantor-set

So I want to prove that the Cantor metric space $(C,|\cdot|)$ is perfect (that is, closed and has no isolated point). However, $C$ is known to be nowhere dense in $\mathbb{R}$, which means that if $x\in\mathbb{R}$ then  $\exists \epsilon > 0$ such that $\forall y\in C$, $|x-y|>\epsilon$. However, this appears to imply that all points of $C$ are isolated. But then $C$ would not be perfect.

So how can it be that a set is nowhere dense, and yet has no isolated points?

Comment: I don't think your description of "nowhere dense" is correct. Its closure (itself since it's closed) contains no intervals. But there is no epsilon, since every point is a limit point.

Comment: @ziggurism But is every point in $C$ an isolated point? Can you please also clarify what a correct definition of "nowhere dense" would look like?

Comment: What makes you think that nowhere dense "means that if $x\in\mathbb R$ then $\exists\epsilon\gt0$ such that $\forall y\in C,|x-y|\gt\epsilon$"? Where did you find that (wrong) definition of nowhere dense?

Comment: A subset $S$ of $\mathbb R$ is *nowhere dense* if, for every open interval $I,$ there is an open interval $J\subseteq I$ such that $J\cap S=\emptyset.$

Comment: A set $X$ is nowhere dense if and only if its closure has empty interior. In this case, the closure of the Cantor set is itself (since it is closed), and indeed it has empty interior since every interval has mercilessly had a hole punched out of it.

Comment: @NoLongerBreathedIn That definition of "nowhere dense" is OK for *closed* sets, It doesn't work for more general sets, e.g. the set of rational numbers, or the set of irrational numbers.

Comment: @bof I didn't understand your definition of a nowhere dense set. Can you please elaborate?

You ask where I took that definition from. Well, I took the definition of a dense subset of a set and simply negated it. But now I'm realizing that I had to do more than that.

Comment: @bof Can you please clarify what the interval $I$ refers to? Is it a subinterval of something?

Comment: @sequence Nowhere dense isn't the negation of dense, it's the negation of "somewhere dense". Anyway, something seems to be wrong with your negation of dense. If you write out the definition of dense that you negated, maybe I can tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: $I$ is an open intervel $(a,b)$ on the real line. A set $S\subset\mathbb R$ is nowhere dense if every interval $I=(a,b)$ contains a subinterval which is disjoint from $S.$

Comment: The definition I was negating is this: A set $S$ is dense in a metric space $(X,d)$ if for every $x\in X$ and $\epsilon >0$ there is $y\in S$ such that $d(x,y)<\epsilon$.

Comment: OK, the negation of "$S$ is dense" is $(\exists x\in X)(\exists\epsilon\gt0)(\forall y\in S)d(x,y)\ge\epsilon.$ So where you wrote "if $x\in\mathbb R$ then $\exists\epsilon\gt0$" you should have written "$\exists x\in\mathbb R\ \exists\epsilon\gt0$" which is quite different. But that's still defining "non-dense" which is not the same as "nowhere dense". For instance, the interval $[0,1]$ is not dense in $\mathbb R$ but neither is it nowhere dense.

Comment: @bof I understand that the negation in my question is not the negation of density, but I was trying to actually say "nowehere dense" this way. That's why I should've said $\forall x\in X, \exists \epsilon>0$ such that $d(x,y)\ge \epsilon$ for any $y\in S$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That definition of a nowhere dense set isn't right. The name itself of that term might be misleading, actually, but I'll try to go through a systematic line of reasoning to show what you're actually supposed to negate.

I apologize if this is too pedantic.

---

First, I'll define what dense means and what "not dense" means below.

> A set $S$ is *dense* in $\mathbb{R}$ if for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon > 0$ there is some $y\in S$ such that $|x - y| < \epsilon$.

I find it easier to think about it in the language of intervals here:

> A set $S$ is *dense* in $\mathbb{R}$ if for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$, every open interval of the form $J = (x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon)$ intersects $S$.

Okay, now the negation of this is:

> A set $S$ is *not dense* if for *some* $x\in\mathbb{R}$, there is an open interval of the form $J = (x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon)$ that is devoid of $S$.

---

Now I'll make precise what might be meant by "somewhere dense" (this is not a real term though):

> A set $S$ is "*somewhere dense*" if somewhere, on some open interval $I$, $S$ is dense on that place.

More formally,

> A set $S$ is "*somewhere dense*" if there exists some open interval $I$ such that $S\cap I$ is dense in $I$.

---

This is what we'd want to negate, and from this we have the following definition:

> A set $S$ is *nowhere dense* if for all open intervals $I$, $S\cap I$ is not dense in $I$.

Now at this point, we expand upon what is meant by "not dense":

> A set $S$ is *nowhere dense* if for all open intervals $I$, there exists some $x\in I$ such that there is an interval of the form $J = (x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon)$ that is devoid of $S$.

---

What this means is that no matter where you look -- no matter what open interval $I$ you look at -- you can find an interval $J\subseteq I$ somewhere there that doesn't intersect $S$.

If I pick a point $z\in\mathbb{R}$, then I can look around that point by examining intervals of the form $I = (z - \epsilon, z + \epsilon)$. 
For every such interval, I can find a $J\subseteq I$ that does not intersect $S$. I can't be sure where $J$ will be ahead of time, but it will be there somewhere. 
Note that $J$ doesn't even have to contain $z$; it just needs to be somewhere in $I$.
Now If I keep decreasing $\epsilon > 0$, then that means I will keep finding $J\subseteq \mathbb{R} - S$ that seem to get "closer and closer" to $z$ (by being bound by $I$).

Now how does this apply to the Cantor set $C$? The set is closed and it has no isolated point because every $z\in C$ has a sequence of points $z_{1}, z_{2},\ldots$ from $C - \{z\}$ that approach $z$. *But at the same time,* you can find a sequence of intervals $J_{1}, J_{2}, \ldots$ that don't intersect $C$ but they also keep getting "closer and closer" to $z$.

When we view it from this perspective, it manages to maintain both properties without any contradiction.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean a sequence of intervals $I_1, I_2, \dots$ is a sequence of "expanding" intervals?

Also, for a definition of "nowhere dense" without using intervals, do you think that my definition is equivalent?:

$\forall x\in X, \exists \epsilon>0$ such that $d(x,y)\ge \epsilon$ for any $y\in S$.

Comment: The difference between our definitions is that in your definition, you say that “this thing happens” _for all_ $x$ whereas in my definition I say that in any open interval “this thing happens” _for some_ $x$ in the interval. Maybe it’s subtle, but your definition is too strong, because it specifies too much knowledge about what $x$ you’re talking about (namely, all of them).

Comment: This has a devastating effect:  if $\forall x\in X, \exists \epsilon > 0 $ such that $|x - y| > \epsilon$ for all $y\in S$, then we will always have $x\not\in S$ because $d(x,x)= 0$. This means $S$ is empty! The definition in my case avoids this because you always need to specify an interval to talk about first, and then you merely know that some $x$ has the definition apply to it.

Comment: I know that the “gaps” of $S$ are everywhere, because they are in every open interval $I$, but the funny thing is that open intervals $I$ can’t ever pinpoint any specific number.

Comment: I changed my post to say $J_{1}, J_{2}, \ldots$ for more consistent notation. "_Do you mean a sequence of intervals $I_{1}, I_{2}, \ldots$ is a sequence of "expanding" intervals?_" I'd actually say the exact opposite. The intervals $J_{n}$ are meant to be getting "smaller and smaller" as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: The demonstration was that given $z\in C$, I can consider intervals of the form $I_{n} = (z -1/n, z + 1/n)$. I apply the definition of nowhere dense to these intervals, and it tells me that every $I_{n}$ contains an interval $J_{n}\subseteq I_{n}$ that does not intersect $C$. As $n\rightarrow \infty$, the intervals $I_{n}$ are _contracting,_ and since $J_{n}\subseteq I_{n}$ the $J_{n}$ are getting closer and closer to $z$, and they're also _getting smaller and smaller._